# How to hide the DOM element with ngShow/ngHide when condition is not met?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, show-hide

I have a `DOM` element that looks like

```
                    <div data-ng-if="allControllerFieldsAreProvided($index)" class="test-controller-connection">
                        <a href="" ng-click="fetchUsersFromDataSource($index, 10)">Test Connection</a>
                    </div>
```

the function looks like

```
 $scope.allControllerFieldsAreProvided = function (adSetupIndex) {
                        return $scope.activeDirectoryConfiguration.activeDirectorySetups[adSetupIndex].name.length > 0 &&
                               $scope.activeDirectoryConfiguration.activeDirectorySetups[adSetupIndex].activeDirectoryDataSource.host.length > 0 &&
                               $scope.activeDirectoryConfiguration.activeDirectorySetups[adSetupIndex].activeDirectoryDataSource.port.length > 0 &&
                               $scope.activeDirectoryConfiguration.activeDirectorySetups[adSetupIndex].activeDirectoryDataSource.userName.length > 0 &&
                               $scope.activeDirectoryConfiguration.activeDirectorySetups[adSetupIndex].activeDirectoryDataSource.password.length > 0;
                    };
```

Initially, when no input is provided, the `DOM` element is hidden, then when all the inputs are provided, the `DOM` element appears.

**Problem**
The issue start when any of the input is deleted again (example, text deleted from input box). In such scenarios, the `DOM` element should disappear, but it is not

How do I fix this?

Comment: if there are no JavaScript errors then it's a logical issue. We can't help you if we don't know the rest of your code in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using a function to evaluate in an ng-if. The reason being the ng-if statement is evaluated every time the digest cycle is run. (which is quite often) Try adding a `console.log('hello')` inside `allControllerFieldsAreProvided` function and you will see what i mean.

If you are using ng-repeat just check the iterated object for the properties you need.

Its also possible to use form validator that will set the form object to $invalid if all the required inputs are not met. then you could use ng-if="!formName.$invalid"

Personally from a ux perspective showing and hiding buttons is bad. i would use `ng-disabled="formName.$invalid"` on a button.

From the sounds of it youre model is not bound properly and you are updating the wrong object when data is changed. Starting by dropping a `<pre>{{activeDirectoryConfiguration  | json }}</pre>` on the page and determine if your model is actually being updated properly.